# calc(100vh - 100px)

Tags: html, css, less

i'm using LESS, and when i calculate `100vh - 100px`, it's been like `100vh - 100vh`. 
 And other, -  `100vh - 10px` is `100vh - 10vh`

Comment: Так это и невозможно вычислить в less на этапе компиляции

Comment: p,s Если что это ru.stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~"calc(100vh - 100px)`. Допустим, `height: ~"calc(100vh - 100px)"`